# Print elements from a db table with confirmation buttons ( Magento - system.xml )

Tags: php, magento, system.xml

I'm developing a custom module with admin configuration.

How can i add a section in the system.xml file in which i can print elements from a db table, with confirm/reject button for each? (it's a variable number of elements, so i cannot create a section for each element)

Is there a way to create a section in which i can add my php code (and only that code) ?

For example, this section has to look like this:

Element-1 {Confirm} {Reject}

Element-2 {Confirm} {Reject}

...